# Is there any way to change the scrollbar icon of the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want the change the scrollbar icon of RecyclerView, so that I can touch the scrollbar and scroll the RecyclerView as I have a large item in the RecyclerView. I do know how tho change the ListView scrollbar icon, but for the RecyclerView I have no idear.

After search on Google, I found that [RecyclerView FastScroll](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/recyclerview-fastscroll-part-2/), I wander if there are any way just like the listview to change the scrollbar icon

Comment: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/LollipopContactsRecyclerViewFastScroller

Answer (score 1):

As android docs said with `android:scrollbarThumbVertical` you can define a Drawble for your vertical scrollbar also if you want to change it's size you can do it with `android:scrollbarSize="Size"`
you can find some related methods at android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollBarStyle%28int%29)

**[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)**

Comment: Thanks! It really change the scrollbar icon, but it seams that it can't drag to scroll the RecyclerView, as like this https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/LollipopContactsRecyclerViewFastScroller. If it can drag it is ok.